# Angular 7 - mat-table com Json complexo

Tags: json, angular

Olá, estou encontrando problemas em popular uma mat-table com um Json que contém subitens.

Minha API retorna:

```html
{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":null,"Data":[{"TagName":"0153_DLD_LD_CCO.02LT05N.F_CV","ErrorCode":0,"DataType":"Float","Samples":[{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:10:00.000Z","Value":"3.982000113","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:20:00.000Z","Value":"3.836999893","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:30:00.000Z","Value":"3.691999912","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:40:00.000Z","Value":"3.542500019","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:50:00.000Z","Value":"3.392999887","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:00:00.000Z","Value":"3.237999916","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:10:00.000Z","Value":"3.082999945","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:20:00.000Z","Value":"2.929500103","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:30:00.000Z","Value":"2.776000023","Quality":3},{"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:40:00.000Z","Value":"2.63049984","Quality":3}]}]}
```

Para um retorno simples, ok, mas e quando tenho uma array em um objeto? No caso eu preciso ler os dados de Samples[]

Via console já verifiquei que o retorno do Json está ok, mas a tabela não carrega os dados.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dadosLeitura" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dadosLeitura"> {{dadosLeitura.Data.Samples.Value}} 
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Você tem dois objetos em um arquivo json... Tem dois objeto com nome data,muito confuso.

Comment: No Json é só um objeto Data, acabe de conferir aqui.

Comment: Desculpe o editor JSON duplicou os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está complexo seu **Json**, como está trabalhando com Angular, Json são muito comuns então tem que conhece-los bem para acessar suas propriedades, pode ver o exemplo funcionando com os seus dados [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tables). No seu caso vc tem um retorno de um `objeto` **{ }** e dentro deste objeto tem a *propriedade* **Data** que é um `array` **[ ]** de objetos, que por sua vez tem a propriedade **Samples** que também é um array de objetos que é onde estão as informações que realmente precisa para preencher a **mat-table**:

```
const RETORNO_API = {"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":null,"Data"[
  {"TagName":"0153_DLD_LD_CCO.02LT05N.F_CV", "ErrorCode":0,"DataType":"Float","Samples":[{
  ...
```

Ou seja vc só precisa do conteúdo de **Samples**, que pode ser acessado assim:

```
const DADOS = RETORNO_API.Data[0].Samples;
```

Que vai gerar o array contendo os objetos:

```
[
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:10:00.000Z","Value":"3.982000113","Quality":3},     
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:20:00.000Z","Value":"3.836999893","Quality":3},
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:30:00.000Z","Value":"3.691999912","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:40:00.000Z","Value":"3.542500019","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T22:50:00.000Z","Value":"3.392999887","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:00:00.000Z","Value":"3.237999916","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:10:00.000Z","Value":"3.082999945","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:20:00.000Z","Value":"2.929500103","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:30:00.000Z","Value":"2.776000023","Quality":3}, 
  {"TimeStamp":"2019-04-22T23:40:00.000Z","Value":"2.63049984","Quality":3}
]
```

Aí é só configurar as propriedades da mat-table:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['TimeStamp', 'Value', 'Quality'];
dataSource = DADOS;
```

E no Html inserir os dados corretamente:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- TimeStamp Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="TimeStamp">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TimeStamp </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.TimeStamp}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Value Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Value}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Quality Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Quality">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quality </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Quality}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Opa! muito obrigado!!!
Testei e funcionou, agora tenho que implementar junto com um token gerado anteriormente.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe serviu de alguma maneira, poderia considerá-la como aceita, para que a mesma não fique como aberta no site?

Comment: Desculpe, me esqueci.